# My app is installed but not showing or running

Tags: android

I cleared all the bugs... Recently before running this app it was showing **"No default activity found"** I changed configuration to **"Nothing"** & also added Android Manifest.xml file.

After successful build, Emulator shows app in settings>>app management.

But,

There is nothing in Apps Menu. Even I tried manually installing this app in my device. But it says **"App Not Installed"**

Share your experience. Help me out. Thank you.

Comment: check your manifest file, lauch activity is there

Comment: share your manifest file